# Javascript CORS Request

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a php web service with CORS enabled.

I used http://www.test-cors.org/ to confirm the web service works. According to this service XHR load event fired and status code is 200.

I copied the code that Test Cors generates into an online javascript console https://repl.it/languages/javascript

Here I always receive 0 for XHR status.

Based on Test Cors my web service is set to allow cross origin. However when I use an online javascript console the same web service returns a status code of 0.

Is there a reason why this code would not work?

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
     //This part is called correctly
     xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } 

    return xhr;
};

var url = <URL>
var method = 'GET';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.loadstart = function() {
    //Not called
}
xhr.onload = function() {
    //Not called
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    // Called
};

xhr.send();

alert(xhr.status)
```

Comment: because you're alerting before you've made the actual request? Also curious what an 'online javascript compiler' is.

Comment: Plus -  I've only ever attached the callbacks BEFORE calling open.   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest.     xhr.loadstart = function() ....  xhr.open(method)...xhr.send().

Comment: @JaredSmith I meant to say console not compiler. With the code above, xhr.onerror is called. Even if I move the alert for xhr.status after the call, the alert is still 0

Comment: @HShhanick you misunderstand: you are expecting asynchronous code to behave synchronously. Every beginning developer trips over this. How you order the statements in the source code doesn't matter in this case. Put the alert inside your `onerror` and `onload` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your alert of the status is made before you send (thus receive) the request, so the status is not yet set and you get 0.
All of your alerts/checks need to be inside onload/onerror, which are executed when the request is complete.